# Compilation error in getting Cursor using sqlcipher

Tags: android, cursor, sqlcipher

I am new to android programming.In my application ,I want to encrypt the database using sqlcipher but facing a compilation error. Please help solving this problem as I have already searched quite a bit but couldn't find a solution.
Already done the required importing for sqlcipher and loaded the libs using SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this).

Thanks in advance..! [Attaching the code]

@Override

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

```
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    String name="",phoneNumber="";

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

               Uri contactUri = data.getData();


   Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri,null, null, null,null);
```

Getting error in the last line: Incompatible types: 
Required : net.sqlcipher.Cursor
Found : android.database.Cursor

Answer (score 1):

You have imported the wrong package to reference the `Cursor` interface when using SQLCipher.  Take a look at your import statements at the top of your file, replacing `android.database.Cursor` with `net.sqlcipher.Cursor`.